# fix/freeze individual kernel weights in a convolutional operation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying out a workaround for fixing individual kernel weights in a convolutional operation in TensorFlow using Python 3.7. I do it by creating

1. a trainable variable,
2. an identical non-trainable variable and
3. a "mask" tensor consisting of **1**s and **0s** with the same shape as the created variables in step 1 and 2 above.

A **1** in the "mask" tensor indicates that I want to fix/freeze that specific weight during training, i.e. not update it in the backward pass.

Now, this workaround works perfectly fine when applied to a fully connected layer but fails when applied to a convolutional layer and I can't figure out why or how to make it work.

Something seems to be happening in the **tf.nn.conv2d()** function call (see code example below) and according to the documentation this is what they do:

> Given an input tensor of shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`
>     and a filter / kernel tensor of shape
>    `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`, this op
>     performs the following:
>     1. Flattens the filter to a 2-D matrix with shape
>        `[filter_height * filter_width * in_channels, output_channels]`.
>     2. Extracts image patches from the input tensor to form a *virtual*
>        tensor of shape `[batch, out_height, out_width,<br>
>        filter_height * filter_width * in_channels]`.
>     3. For each patch, right-multiplies the filter matrix and the image patch
>        vector.

But since I use **weights_frozen** which is a tensor and depends on the trainable variable, non-trainable variable and **mask_weights** it should get zero-valued gradients on the positions where I have a 1 in the **mask_weights** tensor.

```py
def conv(input_, layer_name...):

    weights = tf.get_variable(shape=[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer(), trainable=True)

    weights_fixed = tf.Variable(tf.identity(weights), trainable=False)

    mask_weights = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, weights.shape)


    weights_frozen = tf.add(tf.multiply(mask_weights, weights_fixed), tf.multiply((1 - mask_weights), weights))


    out_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input_, filter=weights_frozen, strides=strides_, padding='SAME')
    out_add = tf.nn.bias_add(value=out_conv, bias=biases_frozen)

    out = tf.nn.relu(features=out_add)

    return out
```

As mentioned, I expect to get zero-valued gradients on the positions where I have a **1** in the **mask_weights** tensor, but instead they are non-zero and therefore those weights are being trained, which is not the behavior I'm trying to achieve.